# get data from datatable query

Tags: c#, list

I have been trying to get the results for the query below and add the data into a list so that I can remove duplicates

```
var w = sqlData.AsEnumerable().Where(data => data.Field<String>("slideNo") == "5")
                .Select(data=> data.Field<String>("QuestionStartText"));
```

this information give out data based on column and I want to go though the variable and put each inderviual string into a lsit

Comment: into one list without duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return sqlData
           .AsEnumerable()
           .Where(data => data.Field<String>("slideNo") == "5"))
           .Select(data=> data.Field<String>("QuestionStartText"))
           .Distinct()
           .ToList();
```

Comment: Assuming `sqlData` is a datatable, don't you need to call `AsEnumerable` first?

Comment: @user1776590 this is provided as an example. you may change it however you need to fit your needs.

Comment: @DaveZych, you may be right. it's been so long since i have worked with `DataTable`

Comment: saying it "not work", doesn't help. you will need to be more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

```
var w = sqlData.AsEnumerable().Where(data => data.Field<String>("slideNo") == "5")
                .Select(data=> data.Field<String>("QuestionStartText")).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Yeah you do? Which version are you using.